# Use Redis in Symfony Insight

Tags: symfony, redis, continuous-integration

According to [the documentation](https://insight.symfony.com/docs/how-to/connect-to-a-database.html), SymfonyInsight has Redis preinstalled. However, I get this error message when running an analysis.

```
 bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

In AbstractConnection.php line 155:

  Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]  


Script bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 111
```

I'm using [default settings](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html) like `redis://localhost`, `redis://127.0.0.1` or `redis://127.0.0.1:6379` but none of them worked.

I can't find how to use Redis. How can I get it working?

Comment: @yivi I've reverted your change, since this is about running Redis in the `composer install` step, not while running analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, but this script helped me out:

```
pre_composer_script: |
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo apt-get install redis-server -y
```